# PHP dynamic type hinting

Tags: php, type-hinting

Given a class:

```
Class Car { }
```

and a string:

```
$className = 'Car';
```

How to typehint an instance?

```
$car = (Car) new $className(); // example
```

**Clarification**

In response to many individuals second guessing my intent, I am seeking type-hinting for IDE auto-completion.

Comment: @JimL, yes, I get a parse error.

Comment: @u_mulder The object is polymorphism and IDE autocomplete.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to achieve, here. If you want to instantiate whatever class the `$className` names, use `new $className`. If you want to instantiate `Car`, use `new Car`. You're obviously trying to achieve *something* more than either of these two options, but... what? Possibly - and I'm wildly guessing now - you're saying that `$className` will contain the name of a subclass of `Car` and you want to instantiate that subclass while hinting to your IDE that `$car` is going to be some kind of `Car` instance? If so, edit your question to say so; at the moment it's unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For autocompletion of dynamically created objects (if its type is not recognized automatically) most IDEs support type-hinting comments.

For example:

```
/** @var Car $car */
```

See http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html

Comment: This might be what the OP is after, but it's hard to tell unless he clarifies the question.

Comment: @Ascaria - Fantastic ! Exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: Another solution that helped my case, is to create a static function in Car class that would create the object: ```public static function createCar(string $nomeConsulta) : Car```, that way, you will be able to specify the return type.